# How to add multiple fields in filter (term) query to simulate OR in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Hello everyone  not sure if the title is clear enough so I will jump straight ahead to the example that I have.

I have some cars inside my index, and all of them have make and model. I am doing a count query and I want to count all combinations. Let's take a look at the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "model": [
                            "a5",
                            "a4"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "make": [
                            "audi",
                            "bmw"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This works but not exactly what I want. There is no relation here between makes and models, but I want to have a relation because `a5` and `a4` are only related to `audi`, not `bmw`, and thats the reason why I am getting the wrong results. It sould count all `a4` and `a5` audis, and all bmws, doesn't matter which model they are, but instead of that I am getting count only for audis, because there is no `a4` and `a5` in bmws.

Ideally, I would use something like this:

```
"filter": [
    {
        "terms": {
            "model": [
                "a5",
                "a4"
            ],
            "make": ["audi"]
        }
    },
    {
        "terms": {
            "make": [
                "bmw"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

but this is not possible due to es error: `[terms] query does not support multiple fields`.

I would be grateful if some of you have the workaround for the issue that I have. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `(make:audi AND model:a4|a5) OR make:bmw` which can be rewritten as a `should` of one `must` of `terms` and one standalone `term` query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "model": [
                    "a5",
                    "a4"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "make": "audi"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "make": "bmw"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```